# Recommendation of forbidden things

Tags: quran, hadith, reference-request, halal-haram

In the past, if someone recommends one of his family members or friends thing which is forbidden in islam then what could be the way to recompense for it ?

Like i recommended to watch a tv series to a brother of mine. Now he is enjoying a lot and appreciates my recommendation. This was all done in my state of ignorance. Also, presently he is not from one of those who give attention to allah . He just live his worldly life. And i keep thinking that because of me he get more involved in doing forbidden things.

**Actual question: Will Allah held both of them responsible, the one who recommended and the one who practiced?**

**What if i warned him not doing this would i be held responsible or i have completed my duty and won't be responsible.**

*References from Hadith and Quran would be appreciated.*

Comment: An example would be helpful. Note that asking about "the best, worst etc." might attract subjective answers.

Comment: Do you really need a narration to tell you recommending something bad is bad? Sometimes that bad thing is super small. But everything big (good or bad) starts with the smallest of things. Just repent and enjoin him to do good and forbid the wrong — if he listens to you.

Answer (score 1):

Repent to Allah and make dua for his guidance and forgiveness.
Advising him that what he's doing is wrong is also a good thing to do